# SSRS Exporting to Excel worksheet name changes based on Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm currently building an SSRS report and it gets rendered to excel. I'm trying to figure out how to set up the report so that it creates multiple Worksheets (Tabs) of the data on the report and to show the names of the excel tabs even when there's is No data in the group.

I know that entering a page break in the report gives you a new names for each worksheet, and that works fine when THERE IS data in the group, but I need the tab names to show when there's NO data in the the group.  Instead of just giving me the name of the report or 'Sheet1'.

**For example:**
My group is called Region and my Parameter is called Region.  If I select the EastCentralRegion on the Parameter and there's no data for that region I would still want the Excel worksheet tab to show 'EastCentralRegion'.

I tried setting the page break to the parameter, but that was only giving me the same results.

Anyone know how this is done?  Let me know if you want some pictures as examples.

Comment: Long time since I last used SSRS but can't you add an empty line for regions with no data to trick SSRS ?

Comment: You're going to need a pseudo table (Left Outer Join to your current data) in your datasource that provides all of the sheet names you need.  Once you have that in place, you will always get every group regardless if it has data.